# Problem with TArcReaderControl

Tags: delphi, activex, delphi-2010, arcgis

I have ArcGIS 10 installed and had previously developed a customised application using the free ArcReader Active-X control (ArcReaderControl). In Delphi 2010 & the previous version of ArcGIS, namely 9.3.1, I imported the Active-X control with no problem at all & could drop it on a form. However, after importing the Active-X control with the ArcGIS 10 version, the minute I try drop the Active-X control on a form I get "ClassFactory cannot supply requested class".

Is anyone able to shed some light on this for me?

Alan

Comment: This message generally appears when a COM object is not properly registered in the system, or when your install a new version of the COM object (OCX in this case) without uninstall the previous version. So my advice is uninstall the ocx and make sure which not exist any dll related to the ArcGIS ocx in the system and then reinstall the OCX again.

Comment: In this particular case, there was no previous version of the control as it was on a new laptop that had never had the older version on it. I can understand that the control may not be registered correctly but i have followed the same steps when registering the previous version on my old laptop as I have with registering the new version on my new laptop.